# All PHP 7.4 are not available in 20.04

Tags: apt, software-installation, php, 20.04

I just did a do-release-upgrade that went fine, but I am still stuck at PHP 7.3.

```
$ apt install php7.4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.4 : Depends: libapache2-mod-php7.4 but it is not going to be installed or
                   php7.4-fpm but it is not going to be installed or
                   php7.4-cgi but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

what is funny is that not all PHP 7.4 are available in APT

```
dpkg -l | grep php7.4
```

return

```
ii  php7.4-bcmath                         7.4.5-1+ubuntu19.10.1+deb.sury.org+1                  amd64        Bcmath module for PHP
ii  php7.4-common                         7.4.5-1+ubuntu19.10.1+deb.sury.org+1                  amd64        documentation, examples and common module for PHP
ii  php7.4-sqlite3
```

Tried removing Ondrej's PPA, `apt clean`, update/upgrade, `apt install -f` without success.

Any idea what it could be?

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution, I reactivated Ondrej's PPA and was able to install PHP 7.4.5 (the latest). I dont know why I still do not see the PHp 7.4 from the official repository